# when i logout and open the app again it goes into rootview not login iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfuser, rootview

I have made a app with the rootview the inbox. i then logout and it goes to login page which is fine but then when i close the app and open it again it goes to inbox.

i am using parse.com and have implemented this code into inbox view did load.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        NSLog(@"current user: %@", currentUser.username);
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
    }
}
```

i have tried this method in view did appear also:

```
 if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
    }
```

but it does not seem to work. i have implemented the rootview in storyboard and all my segues and screen are there.
any idea how i can show login page when user logs out closes app and opens it again?

logout method:

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {

    [PFUser logOut];
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: your code seems fine, check if user successfully logouts by putting a breakpoint on if condition. If user closes the app without logout then [PFUser currentUser] will no be nil as Parse framework persist this object.

Comment: i have put a breakpoint on the condition and it just prints lldb. ill post my log out method in the question above please see

Comment: When you logout, did you set `currentUser` to `nil`?

Comment: After logout check currentUser object, it has to be nil.

Comment: no, i dont think i did,could you show me where i should do it. i also have to segue identifiers with the id@"showLogin" could that be an issue. im new to iOS development.

Comment: @WildFire where should i set it to nil?

Comment: @smithyy in `[PFUser logout]` function, set your `currentUser` to be `nil`. This should be the function `+ (void)logout` in `PFUser.m` file.

Comment: @TengyuLiu it will automatically set to nil, when user logouts afaik.

Comment: PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser]; then currentUser=nil; would that be ok

Comment: @smithyy you can set it to nil in the second line for your logout button listen. Replace PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser]; to PFUser *currentUser = nil.

Comment: i have tried that and still no luck